# Integrating custom database to an ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2008-express

I have an existing database in SQL Server Express, and I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC4 application, which needs to connect to this database.

When I've created my project, I have selected "Individual user account" for the authentication.

My question is, can I connect to my database with Identity and how ? Is there another way to simply connect to my database ?

Comment: I think its better to read more about MVC, read these tutorials: http://www.asp.net/mvc and your question will be answered

Comment: Your problem is that you have two databases, one of them is related to Individual user account and the other one is related to another?

Comment: Ok you were right Hadi Hassan, I think I have a better understanding now. my database is mapped with EF and I can access data. Now I need to handle Identity, which is about authentication